(Un)zooming a canvas is not precise
When I zoom a canvas, usually multiple times, then unzoom the same number of times, the canvas doesn't unzoom the same. Below are the results of 1 zoom in and 1 out. You see the image never goes back to exactly the original size.
This shows what the problem is. I do not think it's a bug, just unexpected behavior.
console.log(bgImageCanvas.width); // original size: 300
 console.log(bgImageCanvas.width*1.1); // zoom in: 330
 console.log(bgImageCanvas.width*.9); // zoom out: 270` needs to be 300

Here's my zoom function:
function zoomBgImage(callBtn) {
  let tempCanvas = createTmpCanvas(bgImageCanvas.width, bgImageCanvas.height);
  let tctx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d")
  let zoomAmount, newZoom;
  
  tctx.drawImage(bgImageCanvas, 0, 0);
  bgImagectx.clearRect(0, 0, bgImageCanvas.width, bgImageCanvas.height);
  bgImagectx.save();

  if (callBtn == "zoomIn") {
    zoomAmount = zoomInAmount;
    newZoom = currentZoom + zoomIncrement;
  } else {
    zoomAmount = zoomOutAmount;
    newZoom = currentZoom - zoomIncrement;
  }

  bgImageCanvas.width = bgImageCanvas.width * zoomAmount;
  bgImageCanvas.height = bgImageCanvas.height * zoomAmount;
  bgImagectx.scale(newZoom, newZoom);
  bgImagectx.translate(panX, panY);
  bgImagectx.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0);
  bgImagectx.restore();
}


You would be much better off storing an original width/height, and always applying your scaling to that. Applying a new scale to a modified size will lead to compound changes, e.g. 1001.2=120, 1201.2=144, etc with each step being larger than the last (or decreasing for "zooming out")

The inverse of multiply is divide. Thus if zoom = width * 1.1 then width = zoom / 1.1 or  width = zoom * (1 / 1.1)

I'm sorry to say this, but your math is wrong.
Note that you're zooming in by scaling the image up by 10%.
Then you're trying to zooming out by scaling the image by 10%. But this is wrong.
If you have a measurement of 100 then scale it up by 10% you'll get 110.
Now, how much is 10% of 110? It's 11. So if you scale it down from 110 by 11 then it will become 99 instead of the 100 you're expecting...
To have the effect you want, you need to scale it down like follows:
const newSize = oldSize * 1000 / 1100;

Or simplify...
const newSize = oldSize * 10  / 11;

PS.: I just followed the mathematical Rule of Three.
In you paticular case, you shoud set the following variables like this:
const zoomInAmount = 11/10; // 1.1
const zoomOutAmount = 10/11; // 0.909090...

